# What would be a viable "Throne" for my human to be lifted by an army of house flies?

Tags: flight, insects, flying-machines

I have this character in my story who controls insects and I wanna have him travel in swarms of house flies. *why house flies?* you ask? Well, two reasons:

- When I was younger they were my favorite animal (seriously, I would make jar habitats for them and breed them).
- The more practical reason: it's more believable that if there would be enough to fly a human around town.

But there is one problem: the average person doesn't have enough surface area on their body to let 11,818,181 flies to grip him and fly.

My question is: what structure would increase his surface area to 2,954,545.25 square inches to let that many house flies grip and fly without adding any more than 30 lbs to a 230 lbs person?

Comment: How do the flies grab and hold the person?  (At least birds have claws on their feet.)

Comment: @RonJohn with their legs

Comment: I don't see the **tiny** hairs on the **little** legs like this being "grabbers".  http://www.tornado-studios.com/sites/default/files/styles/slider_full/public/products/672/reel-360-1/house-fly-rubbing-legs-0000.jpg

Comment: @RonJohn yeah but the the legs(with the sticky pads) could act like a six fingered hand.

Comment: You realize that you're asking for ~2 square kilometers of surface area right? Also, I removed the creature-design tag since this question has nothing to do with designing creatures. Also VTCing as POB while i'm at it since there are hundreds of possible structures that can accomplish your task (assuming you're not actually asking for 2 square kilometers of area). A big fat cape, a cape made of strings, one really really long string, etc etc.

Comment: @Aify yeah that's why I put it in inches, its sounds less plausible when you put it like that

Comment: @Aify i think one of the editors put the creature design tag for some reason, i didn't have it originally

Comment: @Aify well I'm not just asking for any structure it needs to allow the flies to well fly

Comment: A helium filled rubber couch, or couch shaped helium balloon

Comment: With enough thrust rotting pig fly just fine... only problem is acceleration I can only think of a tall building ;D

Comment: I think mythbuster did an experiment like this that showed insects can't pack tight enough when flying to lift any significant weight. https://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/videos/laptop-lift

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**A Peculiar Sort of Cape**

The character wears a sort of rigger's harness under his clothing with a large billowing cape-like garment attached to it. Instead of fabric the cape is thousands of sturdy threads. While thread seems weak, if enough of them are spreading out his body weight over a large enough area no single thread would need to be bearing much more than a few ounces of weight. It would also look mad-creepy. If his abilities are focused and fine-tuned enough (its magic so he can be as in control as you want him to be) he could even have them arrayed behind him in such way that they look like a massive blurred and droning set of flies wings.

[image]

Comment: It's the magic of mind controlling microbots the size of bacteria, but yeah do you have a real world example or a picture of what this would look like, it's a great answer I'm just having a hard tome figuring out what this would look like.

Comment: Poorly drawn picture has been attached.

Comment: Attached to what?

Comment: The original answer, refresh the page and you should see it.

Comment: lol I love it so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I think [human hair would reallisticly be strong enough for the job](https://what-if.xkcd.com/56/), you wish to be even creepier.

Comment: Yes! Hes this cheefully creepy dude with this sort of tim burtonesque air about him. He tries to be nice and jolly but comes across as pesky and weird. He doesnt understand why people hate him so he continues to be irritatingly charming but perverse such as presenting female courtesans with carcass and feces scented "perfume" which he thinks smells wonderful but sickens everyone else present. He floats about whimsically with a cape of human hair supported by the hum of millions of flies at highbrow aristocratic events and mistakes everyone's horror and revulsion for merriment and applause.